# Creating the Azure Data Factory using .NET SDK in .net core?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-search-.net-sdk

Actually I just want to know can I create azure data factory using .net sdk in .net core application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Azure data factory using .net SDK.

Prerequisites for creating Azure data factory using .net sdk is given below:

1. Azure Subscription
2. Azure Roles
3. Storage Account
4. Blob Container
5. Azure Active Directory

You can find code with detail explanation in this [official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net)

Refer - [Github link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net.md)